# how to copy shell programs in remote login linux?

Tags: shell, unix

Our lab has remote login linux.we are practices shell programming .how to copy a shell program one account to another account.everyone have user name password.everyone know the each other user id.
ex.my user name :abu 
      password :abu. give the command with example

Answer (score 1):

You can try ftp

ftp server name/ip

Now enter credentials

Then you will now be that remote server

Go to coressponding location where you need to put your file

put filename//put is key word

Bye//bye is for exit

Alternatively you can get the details from your remote server to your local using get keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scp` command for copying. To know how to use it do `man scp`.

Example:

`scp myfile.txt hope@computerhope: myfile.txt`

The above example would copy the file *myfile.txt* to the *computerhope* server under the name *hope*.

`scp remote:/home/hope/*.`

Copy files in the remote machine in the */home/hope* directory to your local computer.

You can also use `ftp` or `gftp`.

Answer (score 0):

To upload from your directory or to copy using scp

```
scp -r /home/dir/fname location_of_new_dir:/home/dir/
```

The reverse can be used to obtain data from the other location

```
scp -r  location_of_dir:/home/dir/ /home/dir/fnames
```